# How do you throttle Laravel Passport's oauth/clients route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am wondering how to throttle Laravel Passport's oauth\clients route, as well as the route to add a client.

By default the client-related routes are unthrottled, and my entire Web site was attacked and taken down as a result of this issue (by a malevolent user who just spam-added clients).

I have tried the following methods, neither of which work:

```
 \Route::middleware('throttle:30,1')->group(function () {
    Passport::routes();
 });
```

and also

```
Passport::routes(null, [
  'middleware' => [
     'throttle:30,1'
]]);
```

While both of these methods add throttle:30,1 in front of web,auth (verifiable when dumping the route list using php artisan), any attempt to invoke /oauth/clients now results in a 401 unauthenticated error.

I am looking for guidance as to how I can properly throttle these client routes.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked:

```
 Passport::routes();
            \Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'throttle:60,1']], function ($router) {
                $router->post('/oauth/clients', [
                    'uses' => '\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@store',
                    'as' => 'passport.clients.store',
                ]);
            });
```

The previous examples ended up placing throttle middleware before auth, which breaks things for some reason. If you make sure throttle middleware occurs last, then it works.